# How to create a Grid View with fitted to the screen without scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am new using flutter, and I want to create a grid view fitted to the screen and the inner containers height has to change depending of the screen.
For example, I have two devices, in the first one looks well, but in the second one a scroll is generated and I would like that the brown containers would have a lower height to fit on the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lbE0wsVZSw&feature=emb_logo

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: that's not answering anything

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView.builder(
     itemCount: itemCount,
     physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     gridDelegate:                                          
     SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
     crossAxisCount: 2,
     childAspectRatio: (size / size),
      ),
```

try to get you changing the value?